# Call a prompt only on entry to the webpage

Tags: javascript, prompt

I need to call a prompt only on page entry, not on a page load

The page has a form on it so when I submit the form the page reloads, so using the window.onload function won’t work

Can anyone help with some code 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you reload the page with a flag parameter and show the dialog depending on whether that parameter is set or not?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far..?